# Unable to display image in imageview

Tags: java, android, imageview

I'm trying to display a image in the imageview.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    try {
        File imgFile = new File("C:\\photos\\a.jpg");
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (myBitmap == null) {
            Log.e("BITMAP", "myBitmap is NULL");
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);         
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can see the error message "myBitmap is NULL".
Is there anything i need to do, to ensure the path is recognized.

Thanks!

Comment: Log the path also put the image under phone memory or sdcard and then get the path of the image. Also do not harcode the paths

Comment: See my answer and tell what results your have...

Answer (score 1):

The path `"C:\\photos\\a.jpg"` refers to a path in your Windows system, and this is invalid. Android doesn't know anything about Windows.

You need to put the file in your **resources** directory or your **assets** directory, and provide the path accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

try this :
place image in `assets` folder and then:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;
}
```

and then set image Bitmap in `imageView` as:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAsset("fileName"));
```

Or if image file is on `SD card` then try this :

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/photo.jpg");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

hope this will help you.